# Working with SSL Certificates in Android

Tags: java, android, ssl, webserver, ssl-certificate

I'm new to Android programming and SSL. I am trying to make a Messenger app which has a web server in **PHP** and **MySQL** database. I have tested my application in **XAMPP** and it works perfectly, but now I have bought a server which starts with: "**https://**" and i want to upload my web server and database to it. When I give the address of my server in the java codes, it prompts me that there is a problem with **SSL** stuff. I appreciate any help that can tell me how should I start fixing this problem and what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a key store. You can use android-async-http libray, following a sample [CustomCASample](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/1.4.8/sample/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/sample/CustomCASample.java)